# For what values of $N$ is $N^{3/2}$ between $N (\ln N^2)/2$ and $2N \ln N^2$

Tags: algorithms

I am having issues figuring this one out, as I know that once values of N get very large, N$^3$$^/$$^2$ becomes bigger than NLogN without a shadow of a doubt. The problem is that there are a lot of huge values and I'm not sure where the values become "huge enough" for example, I tried 1,000,000 and that was certainly huge enough. Then I went down to 999,999, then tested 10,000.

I'm not sure when cubic square roots start becoming big enough

Comment: Is $\ln N^2$ supposed to be $\ln (N^2)=2\ln N$ or $(\ln N)^2?$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

You *do* know that $\ln x^2 = 2 \ln x$, right?

Solving for $$n^{3/2} = 4 n \ln n$$

or

$$\sqrt{n} = 4 \ln n$$

gives $n = 64 W\left(-\frac{1}{8}\right)^2 \approx 680.87,$ where $W$ is Lambert's $W$ function or ProductLog function.

Comment: With your reading of $\ln N^2$ OP asked about $4x\log(x)$

Comment: I'm describing the basic transformation, relevant to the OP's "$N (ln N^2)/2$", for instance.

Comment: @RossMillikan:  Thanks.  Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

You are asking when $\sqrt N$ becomes larger than $4 \ln N$.  It is always larger than $\ln N$.  [Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sqrt%28x%29%3D%204%20log%28x%29) can show us, but at the moment I can't copy the chart.  The answer is that $4 \ln N$ is larger in the range $1.33488-680.87$ and then $\sqrt N$ takes over.